# Laravel subdirectory root not accessible?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, routes

Quick question that I am sure someone can answer in about 2 seconds.

I have a Laravel project set up and one of the subdirectories is set up for documentation.

I have the following code set up.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'docs'], function(){
    route::get('/', function(){
       return redirect('docs.intro');
    });

    Route::get('/intro', ['as' => 'docs.intro', function(){ return view('docs.intro'); }]);
});
```

When I navigate to "www.site.com/docs/intro" all works fine. However, when I navigate to "www.site.com/docs/" it does not redirect like I was hoping, instead is throws a 403 "forbidden" error. Does anyone know why this is? How can I make this work properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to write 'prefix' => '/docs'

Comment: thanks, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're pointing to a directory that exists, so your webserver is not forwarding the request to Laravel's `index.php`file.

Check your apache / nginx configuration and look for the rewrite rules. If you're using apache, you'll probably find something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

That means that if the directory (`-d`) or the file (`-f`) exist, that rewrite won't happen.

Comment: I've marked this as correct but the reason it is correct was accurate. Here is my update so others can learn. 

I was trying to navigate to a URI if "docs" but because I also had a "docs" folder in my public LARAVEL FOLDER it was causing the conflict. Essentially the laravel app was messing with apache because the public folder had the same name as the URI. PEOPLE -> Don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on apache, run `apache2 -v`
If it's Apache 2.4.x+

1. Change

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` to `Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews`

2. Change

   `Order allow,deny
    Allow from all` to
   `Require all granted`

Id it's not 2.4.X try this in htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If you are using nginx :

1. SSH into your server
2. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
3. Modify the server block to look like this

   ```
   server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

   root /var/www/laravel/public;    **//Modify this according to your project**
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   server_name server_domain_or_IP; **//Modify**

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
   }
   ```

   4. `sudo service nginx restart`